# Dynamic height directive to autofill remaining area

Tags: layout, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

Is there any good implementation of a directive that dynamically change heights of element to fill remaining container's height?

In my layout I've header (actually menu) fixed height in pixels, content area (that could overflow above window height so scroll bars should appear) and sticky footer with fixed height. Also on a left and right of content area there could be panels

So something like that:

```
┌──────────────────┐
│       Header     │ ~100px
├─┬──────────────┬─┤
│P│             ▲│P│
│a│   Content   ▒│a│ fill remaining area, with scroll bars
│n│             ◙│n│
│e│             ▒│e│
│l│             ▼│l│
├─┴──────────────┴─┤
│       Footer     │ ~100px
└──────────────────┘
```

I've tried such solutions:

1. Using height: 100%. But as header/footer are in pixels, so its hard to measure their height in percents, this solution din't solved problem.
2. Using haks like "display: table-row" didn't allowed to have scroll bars for content area

As it is quite common layout for web sites, there are quite a lot of solutions using JS, but mostly all of them were not generic - or without possibility to have scroll bars, or panels would not be possible.

So I as understand, the only solution is to use JavaScript for adjust height of en element, so the best place where to put is directive.

Do anybody have some implementation of directive for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I've this solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nimw68KXJRCU3RZzu3Bc?p=preview

Directive `fill` work this way::

1. Calculate `padding-bottom` + `margin-bottom` + `border-bottom-width` of all elements, that contains current element
2. Add heights of all elements beneath the current element and beneath all elements, containing current element
3. Subtract from window height `offsetTop` of the element and result of previous calculations
4. Set element's height to resulting value

So the idea of height calculation (actually height of area beneath of current element) is:

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║                          ║
║    ╔═════════════╗       ║
║    ║ Element     ║       ║
║    ║ to autofill ║       ║
║    ...............       ║
║    ╚═════════════╨───────╫─────────
║                          ║         + margin/padding
║  ╔════════════════════╥──╫─────────
║  ║ some element       ║  ║
║  ║   below            ║  ║         + height
║  ║                    ║  ║
║  ╚════════════════════╨──╫─────────
║                          ║         + margin/padding
╚══════════════════════════╨─────────
```

There are some restriction:

1. I assume that widths of paddings, margins, borders are specified in pixels (convert from other units seems to be quite complex)
2. I didn't tested it on other browsers except Chrome.

Improvements are welcome!

Comment: This answer is great.  Will this work for Angular 4.0 as well?

Comment: @Lereveme the idea is same, but implementation differ a lot. Also, now it is 2017, so you can use CSS Flex, so no any JS required :)